# Event sourcing - error handling when events are not created

Tags: event-sourcing

As to my understanding, in event sourcing, events are recorded. However that would also mean a state changed first happened and thereafter we record the event. For example, assuming:

1. A Client sends a command to a server to "Create user".
2. The server validates the command and creates user i.e. stores new
   user in a database.
3. The server then logs/stores a `Created User` event. i.e event
   sourcing.
4. `Created User` event is propagated to subscribers

In the scenario above, how do we handle scenarios where step (2) succeeded but step (3) failed due to say network failures, database offline etc? The whole system would be in an indeterminate state now that there was a new user created but the event was never logged. How do we mitigate these types of failures? Or are the steps that I've listed above not the way to do event sourcing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not what happens exactly in Event sourcing, not even in plain CQRS.

In Event sourcing, after the command is validated, the domain events are generated by the source (the Aggregate in DDD) and then they are appended to the Event store in the first step. After that the subscribers (read models, projections, Sagas, external systems) receive and process the new domain events.

In CQRS, after the domain events are generated, they are applied to the Aggregate *and* then the Aggregate's state and the new events are persisted *in the same local transaction*, as the first step. Only after that the subscribers receive the events.

So you see? Your situation cannot happen: steps 2 and 3 are persisted atomically, they succeed or fail together.

Comment: To clarify, in event sourcing, are you saying that no new user (i.e no state change has happened) was created but an event `User created` is logged?

Comment: @user3240644 I'm saying that in ES no user is persisted ever, only the domain events. By contrast, in plain CQRS (without ES) the user and the new events are persisted but in the same transaction.

Comment: @user3240644 is the same as Event sourcing, you persist only the domain events. There is an optimization that you can make called "snapshoting" in which you save , every `n` events, the Aggregate (the `user` in your case) but you do it only when performance is too low.

Comment: Thanks much appreciated. So in other words, for CQRS, the underlying tech (i.e database type) matters since for example, with dynamo db, i'd require 2 tables ( one for the commands/events and one for the state) and dynamo db doesn't guarantee atomic writes to different tables. What tech would be a good choice in this case?

Comment: @user3240644 I don't know, one that have transactions. I don't use plain CQRS.

Comment: @user3240644, You don't need atomic write here, you can create users from UserCreated events completely separate. 
There is only one source of truth - events table. State can be (and should be in CQRS/ES) created at different point of time in different place. It can be even another server with own database.
You can clear state at any time and rebuild it from events again. Consider that as a kind of cache.

Comment: @Karabur I thought about that but assuming I'm creating a user. If i stored a `created user event` but the state hasn't been persisted, how would I validate that the user has been created and not erroneously duplicate the event when the client  issues another create user (i.e same user) command. Realistically i'd have to replay all the events to validate that the user doesnt exist but that would impact performance. Having an atomic write to the state store eliminates this ambiguity. Or do you have a better way?

Comment: @user3240644 it's not so slow to replay all the events. If it becomes, you could use snapshots, but not until you are sure that is too slow.

Comment: @user3240644 First of all, replaying events are fast. How many events you will have on User? I guess it will be dozens, not millions. You can replay hundreds of events in matter of seconds. If you'll have millions - as said above, snapshots to save. 
Secondly - it is not what you can not save user state in a user object - it is just should not be an atomic transaction. CQRS/ES implies eventual consistency - it could be hard to embrace, but you should really understand it.

Comment: Also, read about write/read sides. You can have user object (or repo) in memory and update that at same time you write to db, and then use it for validation. In my experience, unless you have real performance problems, you can just read events and rebuild object state every time you need to do anything. Most probably you are not creating millions of users in a second all the time. AFTER (and if) you'll have performace problems - there are many ways to solve them in simple ways, if system done right.